# Problems with wchar and registry entry

Tags: c, string, windows, wchar-t

So I want to add a string to registry, since the registry strings are to written NULL terminated my string contains a null char in various places.

This is what my string looks like.

`char names[550] = "1DFA-3327-*\01DFA-3527-*\001DFA-E527-*\00951-1500-`

I convert this to `whcar_t` string like so.

```
wchar_t names_w[1000];
size_t charsConverted = 0;
mbstowcs_s(&charsConverted, names_w, names, SIZE);
RegSetValueEx(*pKeyHandle, valueName, 0, REG_MULTI_SZ, (LPBYTE)names_w, size);
```

The registry entry should be

```
1DFA-3327-*
1DFA-3527-*
1DFA-E527-*
0951-1500-*
0951-0004-*
0951-160D-*
```

But this is the registry entry now,

```
1DFA-3327-*
<a box here>DFA-3527-*
<a box here>DFA-E527-*
951-1500-*
951-0004-*
951-160D-*
```

So it eats up the `0` in `0951` also eats up the `1` in `1DFA`

What I have tried:

1> I tried changing the string to

`char names[550] = "1DFA-3327-*\0\01DFA-3527-*\0\001DFA-E527-*\0\00951-1500-`

```
                              ^ ^ Two nulls
```

2> I tried different conversion.

```
for(int i; i < SIZE; i++)
   names_w[i] = (wchar_t)names[i];
```

Comment: Why do you have nul in the middle of your string ?

Comment: @Stargateur This is related to Windows registry. One type of registry entry is a multi string which consists of multiple null terminated strings. Thus the '\0' as separator and a double '\0' as terminator.

Comment: What about `L"blabla"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your string literal.

```
char names[550] = "1DFA-3327-*\01DFA-3527-*\001DFA-E527-*\00951-1500-...\0";
                               ^^           ^^^           ^^
```

You can provide ASCII characters in octal notation (\ooo) or in hexadecimal notation (\x hh).
In your case you provide octal notation and this eats up the next up to three characters. You should change your string to

```
char names[550] = "1DFA-3327-*\0001DFA-3527-*\0001DFA-E527-*\0000951-1500-...\0";
```

or

```
char names[550] = "1DFA-3327-*\0"  // put null byte at end of GUID
                  "1DFA-3527-*" "\0" // add null byte as extra literal
                  "1DFA-E527-*" "\0"
                  "0951-1500-...\0";
```

which also makes it easier to identify the GUIDs in the string.

If you want to use hexadecimal notation then take care that these might eat more than two bytes, so you also need to work with the literal concatenation. (See [How to properly add hex escapes into a string-literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45612822/how-to-properly-add-hex-escapes-into-a-string-literal))

```
char names[550] = "1DFA-3327-*\x00"  // put null byte at end of GUID
                  "1DFA-3527-*" "\x00" // add null byte as extra literal
                  "1DFA-E527-*" "\x00"
                  "0951-1500-...\x00";
```

BTW, is there any reason not to directly store a wide char string?

```
wchar_t names[550] = L"1DFA-3327-*\x001DFA-3527-*\x001DFA-E527-*\x000951-1500-...\0";
```

Comment: Thanks this solved it. Although I need to split the string as `"1DFA-3327-*"  "\x0" "01DFA-3527"`

Comment: Note: Hexadecimal escapes are not necessarily limited to 2 characters, as highlighted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45612822/694733).

Comment: @qwn That's a good idea. It helps keeping an overview over all the GUIDs and makes it easier to separate the GUIDs from each other and from the null bytes.