# Spirit X3, How to fail parse on non-ascii input?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

So the objective is to not tolerate characters from 80h through FFh in the input string. I was under the impression that

```cpp
using ascii::char_;
```

would take care of this. But as you can see in the example code it will happily print Parsing succeeded.

In the following Spirit mailing list post, Joel suggested to let parse to fail on these non-ascii characters. But I'm not sure whether he proceeded in doing so.
[[Spirit-general] ascii encoding assert on invalid input ...](https://sourceforge.net/p/spirit/mailman/spirit-general/?viewmonth=201511&viewday=2)

Here my example code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace client::parser
{
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::x3::ascii;

    using ascii::char_;
    using ascii::space;
    using x3::lexeme;
    using x3::skip;

    const auto quoted_string = lexeme[char_('"') >> *(char_ - '"') >> char_('"')];
    const auto entry_point = skip(space) [ quoted_string ];
}

int main()
{
    for(std::string const input : { "\"naughty \x80" "bla bla bla\"" }) {
        std::string output;
        if (parse(input.begin(), input.end(), client::parser::entry_point, output)) {
            std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
            std::cout << "input:  " << input << "\n";
            std::cout << "output: " << output << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change the example to have Spirit to fail on this invalid input?

Furthermore, but very related, I would like to know how I should use the character parser that defines a char_set encoding. You know `char_(charset)` from [X3 docs: Character Parsers develop branch](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/quick_reference/char.html).

The documentation is lacking so strongly to describe the basic functionality. Why can't the boost top level people force library authors to come with documentation at least on the level of cppreference.com?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/develop/test/x3/char1.cpp#L165) can help you understand how the `char_(charset)` variant works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing bad about the docs here. It's just a library bug.

Where the code for `any_char` says:

```
template <typename Char, typename Context>
bool test(Char ch_, Context const&) const
{
    return ((sizeof(Char) <= sizeof(char_type)) || encoding::ischar(ch_));
}
```

It should have said

```
template <typename Char, typename Context>
bool test(Char ch_, Context const&) const
{
    return ((sizeof(Char) <= sizeof(char_type)) && encoding::ischar(ch_));
}
```

That makes your program behave as expected and required. That behaviour also matches the Qi behaviour:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c9cdacb15f9d902)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

int main() {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    char const* input = "\x80";
    assert(!qi::parse(input, input+1, qi::ascii::char_));
}
```

Filed a bug here: https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/issues/520

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using `print` parser:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace client::parser
{
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::x3::ascii;

    using ascii::char_;
    using ascii::print;
    using ascii::space;
    using x3::lexeme;
    using x3::skip;

    const auto quoted_string = lexeme[char_('"') >> *(print - '"') >> char_('"')];
    const auto entry_point = skip(space) [ quoted_string ];
}

int main()
{
    for(std::string const input : { "\"naughty \x80\"", "\"bla bla bla\"" }) {
        std::string output;
        std::cout << "input:  " << input << "\n";
        if (parse(input.begin(), input.end(), client::parser::entry_point, output)) {
            std::cout << "output: " << output << "\n";
            std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
input:  "naughty �"
Parsing failed
input:  "bla bla bla"
output: "bla bla bla"
Parsing succeeded
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/HSoB8uqMC3WME5yI

---

It is a surprising fact that for some reason the check for `char_` is done only when the `sizeof(iterator char type) > sizeof(char)`:

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <typeinfo>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

template <typename Char>
void test(Char const* str)
{
    std::basic_string<Char> s = str;
    std::cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(Char).name()) << ":\t";
    Char c;
    auto it = s.begin();
    if (x3::parse(it, s.end(), x3::ascii::char_, c) && it == s.end())
        std::cout << "OK: " << int(c) << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Failed\n";
}

int main()
{
    test("\x80");
    test(L"\x80");
    test(u8"\x80");
    test(u"\x80");
    test(U"\x80");
}
```

Output:

```
char:   OK: -128
wchar_t:    Failed
char8_t:    OK: 128
char16_t:   Failed
char32_t:   Failed
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/j9PQeRVnGZQeELFA

Comment: It's a bug. I filed it. Using `print` doesn't really do anything to solve it. The test code should at least read `(print | space) - '"'` to match the use case. (Nitpick, you modified the test case by splitting them. I thought the same initially, but the only reason the string literal was split was because `"\x80b` parses as an invalid char escape in C++....)

Comment: Thanks to both! The input string was meant this way because I followed advice from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45612966/10803387