# Convert universal character name to UTF-8 in C

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, wchar-t

I need to convert universal character name (UCN) data from a database to UTF-8. Seems trivial, but I spent hours reading about unicode, UTF-8, wide strings, ... without any result.

As example, the following string needs to be converted from `D\u00c3\u00bcsseldorf` to `Düsseldorf`.

What I tried:

```
char str[] = "\u00c3\u00bc"; // corresponds to ü
size_t str_len = strlen(str);
for (i = 0; i < str_len; i++)
    printf("%02hhx ", str[i]);
printf("- %zu - %s\n", str_len, str); // prints "c3 83 c2 bc - 4 - Ã¼"
```

`c3` is correct, but the next 3 bytes are unexpected.
The compiler only considers the first part of the UCN (`\u00c3`).

```
wchar_t wcs[] = L"\u00c3\u00bc";
size_t wcs_len = wcslen(wcs);
for (i = 0; i < wcs_len; i++)
    printf("%02hhx ", wcs[i]);
printf("- %zu - %ls\n", wcs_len, wcs); // prints "c3 bc - 2 - Ã¼"
```

Looks better.
The entire UCN is considered (`c3 bc`), but still no `ü`.

```
char str[] = "\xc3\xbc";
size_t str_len = strlen(str);
for (i = 0; i < str_len; i++)
    printf("%02hhx ", str[i]);
printf("- %zu %s\n", str_len, str); // prints "c3 bc - 2 ü"
```

This prints the `ü`, but I modified `str` from UCN to hex code.

What am I missing to get from `\u00c3\u00bc` to `ü`?

**--- UPDATE ---**

Like [Rob Napier described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78028071/3657691), I have to change the initial string literal since it was badly/double encoded. I believe the only solution would be to manually change to `"D\u00c3\u00bcsseldorf"` to `"Düsseldorf"` or `"D\u00fcsseldorf"`. Both ways require manual change.

Changing it to `"D\xc3\xbcsseldorf"` produces the correct result `"Düsseldorf"`, but only by coincidence because the byte following the second byte injection (`\xbc`) is non-hex (the letter `s`). `"AAA\xc3\xbcBBB"` gives `"AAAû"` (`0x41 0x41 0x41 0xc3 0xbb`). Too bad that `\x` in a string literal doesn't stop after 1 byte. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45612966/3657691).

Comment: Note: you data is not UCN: the use of `\u` is done wrongly (probably a double encoding). Probably for such reason you cannot use common solution. Just interpret `\u00` as `\x`, as you found on second part. Just on first part you interpret `'u` as `\u` sequence and you get the correct result (which need to be interpreted as bytes and doing the utf-8 decoding. (and my tip: avoid `wchar_t`: seldom helps (but if you have API which use it): just an historical accident (before utf-8)

Comment: `\u00c3` is the universal character LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE Ã and `u00bc` is the universal character VULGAR FRACTION ONE QUARTER ¼. OTOH `\xc3\xbc` is UTF-8 for LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS ü, that is `\u00fc`. If you have literally `"D\u00c3\u00bcsseldorf"`, your data is garbled. My half-educated guess is that somebody had a string that was originally UTF-8, tried to escape non-ASCII  bytes incorrectly, and ended up with `u00ZZ` where `\xZZ` should have been used.

Comment: Another possibility is that somebody started with a UTF-8 string, misinterpreted the bytes as Latin-1 (which gives "DÃ¼sseldorf"), converted the misinterpreted Latin-1 string to Unicode (any encoding), and finally printed the resulting Unicode string, replacing non-ASCII characters Ã and ¼ with their UCNs.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: it is just double encoding. Not so seldom in general. We do not see often having the `\u` in double encoding (because it should show some awareness about Unicode)

Comment: What are the actual bytes read from the database? The code shows arrays of `char` with string literal initializers containing UCNs, but UCNs are only a source code representation of a character, not an external representation of a character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char str[] = "\u00c3\u00bc"; // corresponds to ü
```

This is where you went wrong. This is not `ü`. This is `Ã¼`, just as is being output.

- [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=%5Cu00c3&B1=Show)
- [VULGAR FRACTION ONE QUARTER](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=%5Cu00bc&B1=Show)

The UCN for `ü` is `\u00fc`: [LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=%C3%BC&B1=Show)

```
$ uni print c3 bc
     CPoint  Dec    UTF8        HTML       Name (Cat)
'¼'  U+00BC  188    c2 bc       &frac14;   VULGAR FRACTION ONE QUARTER (Other_Number)
'Ã'  U+00C3  195    c3 83       &Atilde;   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE (Uppercase_Letter)

$ uni id ü
     CPoint  Dec    UTF8        HTML       Name (Cat)
'ü'  U+00FC  252    c3 bc       &uuml;     LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS (Lowercase_Letter)
```

Unicode code points (which are what UCN encode) assign a single number to each Unicode character. They are the identifier for the character, not the encoding.

What you've written here is the UTF-8 encoding of `ü`. UTF-8 is a way of writing down Unicode code points. Except for ASCII values (0-127), the UTF-8 bytes are always very different from the code point's value. (UTF-8 is possibly the most clever and useful text encoding ever devised. [But it is not trivial to understand.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding))

If you want to hand-encode UTF-8, then the `\x` syntax is correct. You can inject arbitrary bytes into a C string that way. Generally you should prefer the `\u00fc` syntax when expressing a character, however.

The reason your first byte seemed correct is that the UTF-8 encoding of Ã is c3 83. "c3" is the first byte of the UTF-8 encoding of many modified Latin characters. Seeing a lot of c3 bytes is an easy way to detect Western European UTF-8 text.

Comment: That explains a lot! Thanks! When you say that I can "inject arbitrary bytes into a C string", does this mean that `"AAA\xc3\xbcBBB"` should print `"AAAüBBB"`? If yes, it doesn't. But `"AAA\u00fcBBB"` does.

Comment: Related to the topic - how did you set `UNICONF` in order to get this (very useful) `uni print c3 bc` output?

Comment: This is one of my favorite lookup tools: https://github.com/arp242/uni

Comment: I see you found the problem with `\xc3\xbc`. Yeah, it is a frustrating fact of C syntax. You wind up needing `"AAA\xc3""\xbc""BBB"` or something similar, which is a bit silly, but does handle it.

Answer (score 5):

As correctly explained by @RobNapier, the initial encoding posted in the question is incorrect and results in double encoding if the compiler uses UTF-8 to encode unicode escapes in 8-bit strings.

To ensure UTF-8 encoding on all platforms, you should indeed use hex escape sequences as in `"D\xc3\xbcsseldorf"` and to avoid potential problems with subsequent characters in case they happen to be hex digits, you should use split the string string literal after the hex sequence:

```
    char city1[] = "D\xc3\xbc""sseldorf";
    char city2[] = "Saarbr\xc3\xbc""cken";
```

You could also use macros to avoid typos:

```
#define u_umlaut  "\xc3\xbc"

    char city1[] = "D" u_umlaut "sseldorf";
    char city2[] = "Saarbr" u_umlaut "cken";
```

This is only necessary if the source code does not use UTF-8 already of if the compiler is broken or misconfigured and converts the source character set to a different character set at compile time.  With a modern properly configured system the source can be made more readable as:

```
    char city1[] = "Düsseldorf";
    char city2[] = "Saarbrücken";
```

Comment: Understood. All clear now. I cannot change the strings in the source code as data comes from a database. But I can/will change every individual record inside the database into its correct non-ASCII character (Düsseldorf, ...).